# Trying to put textview in scrollview (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextview

I am trying to make a `scrollview` view all the text inside a `textview`, but nothing is showing when I run my app. A link to two images is below, one shows the objects I have in my view controller and the other shows the attributes of my `textview`.

**Objects:**

[image: objects in view controller]

**Attributes:**

[image: attributes of textview]

**Constraints**

[image: http://i.imgur.com/BCBsFL2.png]

Why is it not working?

Comment: I think you have to remove auto-layout warnings first.

Comment: It doesn't do anything when I click 'update constraints'. It just shows up again.

Comment: Okay so I deleted the textview and put a new one in, and the constraints worked and the warning is now gone, but when I run the app, it still stops me from scrolling down further than the view height.

Comment: You need to show us the constraints

Comment: `UITextView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, so it can scroll itself.  Why  do you need to make your `UITextView` a subview of a separate `UIScrollView`?

Comment: You do know that TextView is a subclass of UIScrollView and it supports automatically scrolling the contents when it's more than textview's bounds? (Unless you have another reason..) I will remove the scrollview, and just add textView directly to 'View' rather than adding hierarchy of views (unless you have a reason).

Comment: I need the scrollview, because I am going to be adding a button at the bottom, just for the purpose of this question I didn't have the button.